# Why DateTimePicker returns obsolete value in the Leave event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms

While working with `DateTimePicker` as a time editor, I experienced a weird behaviour...
I wanted to check the newly entered value in the `Leave` event handler, aiming not to handle each `ValueChanged` event when a user edits hours, then minutes, then seconds..
But it appeared that if a user edited only hour, and the new value contained only one digit, then `dateTimePicker1.Value` in the `Leave` event handler returned the old value.

To reproduce this behaviour it's enough to create a new form, put a `DateTimePicker` and a `Button` on it, and add the following code:

```
    public TimeTestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        dateTimePicker1.Leave += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_Leave);            
    }

    static string text;

    void dateTimePicker1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text = dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"), text);
    }
```

Then when the project is launched you see:

[image]

Then you press:

1. say, `1` on your keyboard
2. press `Tab` to move focus to the button
3. press `Enter`

And see the message:

[image]

Such behaviour does not take place:

1. if you click the button with the mouse
2. if you move focus within `DateTimePicker` to minutes or seconds
3. if you enter hour containg two digits

How can I overcome this? Or, probably, could I use some other event to check the new value instead of the `Leave`?

---

Even more fun...If we edit the code a little:

```
    public TimeTestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        dateTimePicker1.Leave += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_Leave);            
        dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged);
    }

    static string text;

    void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text = dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        MessageBox.Show(text, "ValueChanged");
    }

    void dateTimePicker1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text = dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        MessageBox.Show(text, "Leave");
    }
```

we can see a nice thing:

1. `ValueChanged` fired first:

[image]

2. `Leave` fired after:

[image]

Comment: I don't have anything to contribute other than to say the Win32 date/time control is horrendous and I hope WinForms doesn't build on top of that.

Comment: *I wanted to check the newly entered value in a Leave event handler* Perhaps [`Control.Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you want.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I've just checked your suggestion...`Validating` also return the old value...I'm kinda shocked

Comment: and `Validated` does this as well

Comment: The first mishap is entirely normal, the DTP doesn't update its Value property until the mythical "the user is done typing" notification.  Which happens *after* the message box jerks the focus away.  No repro for the second mishap, you should mention your Windows version.

Comment: @HansPassant it's Win7 Enterprise x64 with project launched on .NetFramework 4 full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in the `LostFocus` event handler `datetimepicker1.Value` returns the new value...so it seems I may use it.

However I'd love to know a deep explanation of how things work here.

Comment: I cannot find a LostFocus event on the DateTimePicker. Is this VB only ?